# Genetic algorithm converging immediately on extremely low optima and very slowly

Tags: python, machine-learning, mathematical-optimization, genetic-algorithm, nonlinear-optimization

I have started in the noble endeavor of getting the (somewhat) higher ups of the company I work at to at least consider ML. I work in automotive so the bulk of our "problems" have to do with things like finding the perfect distance between the car's center of gravity and its back and front wheels, the ideal weight etc.

So the entire deal can be formulated as a fitness function ripe for optimization.

The actual function works like this: we get a number of test cases, lets say 10-15, test cases representing cornering at 100 kph, lane switching at 150 kph etc. and we have a universal test function that, given a set or parameters(like mentioned above) returns an error percentage. For example:

```
get_error(test_case = lane_switch_100kph, 
    weight = 2000, // kg
    front_axle_dist = 1.3, // meters
    back_axle_dist = 1.4  // meters
)
```

And this function return a float in the interval [0, 100] that specified the "error", how much the car deviates from the ideal path when these particular parameters are used. This error needs to be brought below 10%.

I threw together a genetic algorithm (if it matters, I did it in python, using the DEAP library) and tested in with the Rastrigin function and all was great. For the fitness function of the actual simulation I used the mean of the squared errors for all test cases.

On paper this looked simple enough. As a start I need to optimize a more general simulation that only has 4 parameters, so a 4 variable function, which should be simple enough for a genetic algorithm to solve, it fared great with Rastrigin in 100 dimensions so a 4 dimensional function should be a piece of cake.

This particular model was already done by hand a few weeks prior and it is possible to get the error below 10% on all test cases.

Problem is the algorithm, while it DOES improve the mean square error, it does so extremely slowly. For 11 test cases, with the initial errors hanging around 10-30% and the initial MSE hanging around 800 the algorithm seems to be in the final phase of converging right away, going from ~800 slowly (1-3 MSE decrease per generation) to about 725-750 and converging there.

I did not do any optimizations to the algorithm as I figured I would do that after I get a proof of concept done.

My current implementation details are:

1. 4 dimensions as I said, each with its own lower and upper bound.
2. Mutation is selecting one of the 4 dimensions randomly and randomizing its value.
3. Mutation probability is 0.3.
4. Crossover is simulated binary bounded.
5. Crossover probability is 0.6.
6. I do the crossover and then the mutation on random samples of the population.
7. Population size is about 50.
8. I'm using tournament selection with a tournament size of 1/4 of the population.
9. Every generation 3/4 of that generation get selected, 1/4 are replaced with new individuals.

Optimizations I planned on using but have not implemented yet.

1. Elitism.
2. Adaptive mutation parameters using a clustering based method as described here: https://matlab1.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/Clustering-Based-Adaptive-Crossover-and-Mutation-Probabilities-for-Genetic-Algorithms-matlab1.com_.pdf

I am kind of stumped on how exactly I should proceed as the algorithm kind of... getting trapped into a particular local optima right from the start on multiple runs is something I did not even think could happen and have no idea how to fix. Any suggestion would be appreciated alot. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Two things: a) I think your mutation probability is much too high, while crossover probability is too low. You try do to crossover for each sample of population? b) get_error function returns MSE or % error? You should same measurement (% or MSE) for both optimisation function (get_error) and for getting real results... Also try to remove last step, mutation only should do the thing instead of getting new individuals. Are you sure that your random function is working correctly ? EDIT: One more thing - you should always find BEST sample of your population, not MSE for whole population

Comment: @Mazi we have that get error function and the fitness function calls it on every test case, returning the mean of the squares of the results returned by `get_error` for each test case. I am using the same metric. And thank you, I'll try what you said.

Comment: So it looks correct. I would suggest first to try with only one variable (dimension) to be optimised by algorithm and see if it works correctly... Are you sure you can go with your dimensions bounds under 725-750 MSE? Also, try to run it for much more generations maybe?

Comment: @Mazi unfortunately, 4 is the lowest number of dimensions where it makes any sense to do it. And I did try to leave it for more generations, problem is it converges after 2-3 or so. And the changes from one generation to the next become something on the scale of 0.0001

Comment: Well, only suggestion I have is to manually check  what parameters for each dimension are for each generation and find what's wrong by hand for one or two test cases. Try to print to output parameters for each generation and see... 4 parameters is not much